# How can I create PPT readable XML from JavaScript (browser)?

Tags: javascript, svg, powerpoint, openxml, pptxgenjs

I have an app where users create designs that they can then export to SVG via JS.

Unfortunately, SVG is mostly incompatible with PPT and I need to create a separate export format.

How should I export graphical data to a PowerPoint format?
I tried `pptxgenjs`, but there isn't enough flexibility there.

Is there a single XML file I can export (similar to SVG) that is readable by powerpoint?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. openxml is an XML file format so write that.

Comment: >> Unfortunately, SVG is mostly incompatible with PPT 
This specific SVG, or in a specific version of PowerPoint or ???   PPT does import and export SVG as long as you have a fairly recent version.

Comment: Yeah, consider exporting to DrawingML. There can be a lot of similarities between the DrawingML, especially conceptually, but it can get complex quickly depending on your SVGs. Things like strokes and paths and fills aren't much of an issue, but if you have SVG filters, patterns, etc. it would require a lot more work. I'm doing the opposite, DrawingML to SVG. As far as getting any exported DrawingML into a PowerPoint, you'd have to insert it programmatically like through the Open XML SDK or POI, or other packages. You can also copy it directly to the windows clipboard in LockedCanvas format